# Get factor variable name without using apostrophs

Tags: r, dcast

How could I refer to a variable new in a function without writing them as string or indexing before. I want to construct a function where I can replace grouping variables easily.

## For example:

```
final_table %>% data.table::dcast(Lipids ~ combi_new)
```

Another time this factor variable could be named differently.
e.g., group_2
It doesn't work with `final_table[,2]` - how could I solve this?

Thanks,
Nadine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, are you trying to build the formula for a `dcast` from the column indices?
Maybe that answers your problem:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(final_table)
colnames(final_table)
measurevar <- colnames(final_table)[2]
groupvar <- colnames(final_table)[1]
valvar <- colnames(final_table)[3]
formula <- as.formula(paste(measurevar, groupvar, sep=" ~ "))
test <- dcast(final_table, formula, value.var = valvar)
```

Comment: Yes I had difficulties expressing my trouble. But you are good.  "as.formula" solved my troubles. Thanks a lot!